# Как вывести данные в GridView с динамическим набором колонок?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Пытаюсь вывести в

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $columns,
    ]);
?>
```

данные из $dataProvider. Заранее не известен состав колонок, их название и тип данных в них (выбирается пользователем).
Колонки должны формироваться примерно так:

```
$columns[] = ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {link}'];
foreach (что тут должно быть чтобы сформировать колонки???) {
        $columns[] = [
            'attribute' => attribute_id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) {...},
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => $width]
            ];      
    }
```

Если я делаю так:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     // 'columns' => $columns,
    ]);
?>
```

, то данные выводятся но не управляемо, а мне нужно управлять выводом, форматировать даные в ячейках в зависимости от типа, добавлять атрибуты и т.д. Пока нет ясного понимания как строится Gridview...
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сформировать колонки в цикле Foreach, откуда вытаскиваются данные колонок? Понял, что сами данные присутствуют в переменной $models, [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) опять же говориться о переменной $model, вобщем запутался

Comment: используется ActiveDataProvider, запрос для него строится с помощью yii\db\Query()

Answer (score 1):

Какой dataProvider используешь? Допустим это ActiveDataProvider.
Модель это результат запроса query. Множество моделей. 
Данные берутся из аттрибутов модели. Или из связей. 
Если свойство columns не определенно в инстансе gridView, в таком случае он выводит все аттрибуты из моделей. Каждый row это модель, каждая колонка это аттрибут.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Post::find(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);

 // get the posts in the current page
 $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();

GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
         [
             'value' => function($model) {
                 // $model instance of post
                 return $model->author . '/' . $model->title;
             }
         ]
         [
             'attribute' => 'author' //$model->author|$model->getAuthor();
         ],
         [
             'value' => 'author'     //$model->author|$model->getAuthor();                                        
                                     // No attribute - No sort
         ],
         [
             'value' => 'author.name'     // Value from relation.Get  author name
         ],
    ]
]);
```

Вообще затея стремная, можно получить список всех ключей и потом пройтись по ним циклом, а потом еще раз пройдет gridView :\ Если это пользовательские данные тогда стоит взглянуть в сторону формата колонки т.к. 'format' => 'raw' все пропустит.

```
 $posts = $dataProvider->getKeys();
```

**Edit:**
Не вижу смысла все крутить два раза.
Можно передать свойство value как анонимную фун-ю в DataColumn и в ней делать все что необходимо. Тяжело понять, что на самом деле вам нужно.

У себя я делаю так:

$dataProvider использует ActiveQuery OrderStatisticsSearch, у которого определены аттрибуты как в gridView.

```
        <?php echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider'   => $dataProvider,
            'filterSelector' => '#filter-form .js-date-value',
            'showFooter'     => true,
            'columns'        => [
                [
                    'attribute' => 'visitors',
                    'label'     => Yii::t('statistics', 'visitors'),
                    'footer'    => ArrayHelper::getValue($total, 'visitors')
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'orders',
                    'label'     => Yii::t('statistics', 'Orders'),
                    'footer'    => ArrayHelper::getValue($total, 'orders')
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'sales',
                    'label'     => Yii::t('statistics', 'Sales'),
                    'footer'    => ArrayHelper::getValue($total, 'sales')
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'income',
                    'label'     => Yii::t('statistics', 'Income'),
                    'format'    => 'currency',
                    'footer'    => Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(ArrayHelper($total, 'income'))
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'hardToDisplay'
                    'value'     => function($model) {
                         return $this->render('something', [
                             'model' => $model
                         ]);
                     }
                ]


.....
```

Comment: вы имеете в виду сначала обработать\подготовить данные из массива    $dataProvider->models а потом подсунуть обработанный массив в GridView без указания параметра 'columns'? но тогда не выводятся сортировки и фильтры.

Comment: Вышло задуманное?

Comment: пока нет :-(, это какая то жесть...

Comment: Скинь пример, что у тебя есть на входе и что нужно на выходе